# Multi Class Image Segmentation Unet

Tags: image, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution, image-segmentation

I am trying to train [tenserflow U-net](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet), for multi-class segmentation of heart. I have 3 labels and the prediction has 3 probability maps (one probability map for every label). I trained with momentum optimizer which is also the default optimizer of the network. In the very beginning iterations, the probability mapping of label 1 and label 2 are different but after some iterations (or epochs) the probability map of label 1 and label 2 become exactly like each other and technically I have a binary label segmentation. I have seen other networks that have similar architecture like U-net and they have trained on the multi-class dataset. I want to find some multiclass segmentation examples with U-net but all examples are binary.

Comment: A little late comment about this question. I found this question when looking for multi-label segmentation. I think the "multi-label" term is wrong here. You should have used "multi-class segmentation" term. In multi-label problems, each instance (pixel in this case) can be assigned more than one label. Whereas in multi-class, each instance can be assigned only one of the labels.

Comment: I agree with your point that the title should be "multi-class" instead of "multi-label" and thanks for your comment.